# finding distribution $XY$ in bivariate normal distribution

Tags: statistics

suppose $(X,Y)\sim\mathcal{N}(0,0,1,1,\rho)$.
how can find distribution $$Z=XY$$
please explain completely

Comment: Still not found the *accept* button?

Comment: If $\rho=1$, it's a chi-square distribution with $1$ degree of freedom.  If $\rho=-1$, just multiply the chi-square random variable by $-1$.  But for $\rho$ between $0$ and $1$, I'm not sure this is easy to do, unless maybe by numerical methods.

Comment: See [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/405304/119261) answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Start by defining a map $(X,Y)\rightarrow (Z,V)$ by $$Z=XY$$ and $$V=X$$. Use a method of transformation to calculate the density of $(Z,V)$ and then integrate out to get the marginal distribution of $Z$.

Comment: Have you tried this approach yourself? The inverse transformation $X = V, Y = Z/V$ worries me a bit since $X$ and $Y$ are correlated and you have to integrate the joint density to get the marginal density of $Z$.